# KDevelop failed to configure projects

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

after setting up KDevelop under Kubuntu 19.10 with CMake, the following error occurs whenever I open a project:

> Failed to configure the project (error message: Configuration failed.).

As a result, KDevelop's code understanding will likely be broken.
To fix this issue, please ensure that the project's CMakeLists.txt files are correct, and KDevelop is configured to use the correct CMake version and settings. Then right-click the project item in the projects tool view and click 'Reload'.*

If I ignore the message, I can compile my project without any issues, the CMakeLists.txt is set up correctly. I have no idea where to solve this error, I haven't found anything for this specific case on google.

**EDIT**: Additional information

KDevelop Version: 5.4.2

CMake Version: 3.13.4

Upon creating a new KDevelop project, I create "new from template", choose the KDevelop Category and the standard "Simple KDevelop Plugin" as project type. After creation, it instantly prompts me with said error.

In the picture below, you can see the CMake configuration for the newly added project.

[CMake project config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPGRi.png)

Comment: Can you please create a simple [mcve] project which replicates this behavior and show it to us? And what version of KDevelop are you using? What version of CMake?

Comment: And if you create a new project from inside KDevelop itself, does it report the same warning when you later close and reopen the project? If not, what are the differences between such a simple project and one that you made yourself that causes the warning?

Comment: I added more information in the post. Creating a new project from inside KDevelop produces the same error when I close and reopen it. I

Comment: If you really want to make a new KDevelop plugin, you need the kdevplatform headers. Those should be in the `kdevplatform-dev` package. For regular development you probably do not need those.

Comment: Lol, thanks. I dont want to make a new KDevelop plugin, I just chose that option because it defaulted me into it. Well, choosing the "standard" category for a simple cmake c++ project does not produce any errors. Thank you for pointing out that obvious mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:
`base-devel`
`extra-cmake-modules`

To install:
`apt install extra-cmake-modules`
If that doesn't work, you might need to add some repos. [Check this discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859824/how-can-i-install-extra-cmake-modules-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty)

Explanation:

I had a similar problem and got:

```
Failed to configure project 'me_first_proj' (error message: Exit code 1). As a result, KDevelop's code understanding will likely be broken.
```

Inside `CMakeLists.txt` I found it looking for `$ECM_MODULE_PATH` which turned out to be empty.
This, was related to `extra-cmake-modules` which I didn't have.

For Arch: `pacman -Syu extra-cmake-modules`
The name might differ for your distro.

I already had `base-devel` but required `ECM`